# Spring app, стрим звука

Tags: java, html5, spring

Нужно добавить в spring boot приложение проигрывание звука.
HTML тег не проигрывает.

```
<audio controls>
        <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Я так понимаю проблема в том, что передать нужно поток? Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать соответствующие библиотеки для этого, в зависимости от того на чем построен Front-end. Тоесть это Angular, React или Jquery.

Здесь некоторые решения:

- https://issue.life/questions/44883501/play-sound-in-angular-4
- [Play sound in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44883501/11141611)